# what has changed about groovy class properties after the GINA book?

Tags: groovy

I am reading the Groovy in Action (GINA) book. In chapter 9, there is this listing:

```
class MyClass {
    def first = 1
    def getSecond() { first * 2 }
    public third = 3

}

obj = new MyClass()

keys = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'class', 'metaClass']
assert obj.properties.keySet() == new HashSet( keys )  // fail
```

However, the following assert is actually the right one:

```
keys = ['first', 'second', 'class']
assert obj.properties.keySet() == new HashSet( keys )
```

So, what has changed about groovy class properties after the GINA book? Thank you.

Comment: Good to know that you are trying to run the examples from the book. Actual way of learning Groovy. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro, thanks for the encouragement. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [forum for the book](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=21384), it looks like that bit was an error,  or something changed and no one is sure what.

You're better getting access to the [MEAP second edition](http://www.manning.com/koenig2/) of the book as this covers groovy 2